# bash variables and regex comparison

Tags: regex, bash, variables, puzzle

Let `x='abc.xyz'` and `y='abc:xyz'` so that the following holds true (prints "matches" and "diff"):

```
[[ "${x}" =~ abc".xyz" ]] && echo "matches"
[[ "${y}" =~ abc".xyz" ]] || echo "diff"
```

Now, literal `l=".xyz"` can be extracted and tests still work (note double quotes around `l` refs):

```
[[ "${x}" =~ abc"${l}" ]] && echo "matches"
[[ "${y}" =~ abc"${l}" ]] || echo "diff"
```

And the problem: if we try further `r="abc\"${l}\""` or `r="abc${l}"`, the first test never prints "matches":

```
[[ "${x}" =~ ${r} ]] && echo "matches"
[[ "${y}" =~ ${r} ]] || echo "diff"
```

What should be the proper form of `r` to pass both tests?

Comment: It works fine for me

Comment: @anubhava No, it didn't. It is a delicate bash problem.

Comment: Of course it does, [see this demo](http://ideone.com/0nnx7v)

Answer (score 1):

The shell removes normally all unquoted `"` from the command line (they control
only if arguments should be splitted or not), but there
is special handling after `=~`. The quotes work here like escapes,
everything between the quotes are handled as raw characters matching only
itself (beside the variable substitution with `$` that still work).

There is only one evaluation of the pattern, therefore quotes
hidden in variables are considered as regular quotes, and do
not trigger the special quote syntax.

You need to escape the `.` (or any other active) character in `$l`
and the quote syntax does not work in variables.

If `$l` is always equal to `.xyz`, you can use `r="abc\\${l}"` to get the correct match. 
It is equal to `r='abc\.xyz'`.

Comment: Putting `\\` into the `r` assignment is very odd (since it assumes knowledge of the contents of `l`). That should go in `l` I would think.

Comment: @Etan Reisner - you are right but it is workaround, definitely not an elegant solution - one can quote all metachars in `l`. Something like `${l//./\.}` would work given special case `l=".xyz"`. In general case (for example `l` known only at runtime) parenthesis, brackets, and so on should be treated in the same way. It should be kind of `function quote() ...` and called from code.

Comment: @jofel - there is better way to do it than quoting all metachars in `l`. According to docs `Any part of the pattern may be quoted to force the quoted portion to be matched as a string.` It works for pattern `abc".xyz"`, it works for `abc"${l}"`, real pain is the introduction of `r` and subsequent dereference.

Comment: @j.l. Thanks, I extended/rewrote my answer. I do not think, that the pattern is re-evaluated, i.e. quotes in variables work.

Comment: @jofel Please note `l` can be pretty anything (even unknown if it comes from stdin or like). One solution (which you presented) is quoting all metachars in `l`, i.e. using `${l//...}` instead of `${l}`. Second, the elegant one, would be to treat whole `${l}` as literal sequence. It is well supported in bash using double quotes on any pattern subregion. The hard part is variable expansion in the [[ ]] builtin context: neither `r="abc\"${l}\""` or `r="abc${l}"` or even `r="abc"${l}""` works.

Comment: If you do not need regular expressions at all, also `echo ${x} | fgrep -q "${r}"` instead of `[[ .. ]]` should work.

Comment: @jofel Well, in fact it can be written in a form `[[ "${x}" =~ abc"${l}" ]]` and no regex gets sacrified while `l` is properly quoted. Just like orig post shows. But I'm curious about the `[[ ]]` problem.

Comment: There is a bash version issue at play here as well. The quoting rules for the right-hand side of the `=~` operator changed in bash 4.0. The details here (about quoting making `.` literal in variable expansions, etc.) is 4.0+ behavior. The "portable" way of using `=~` is to store the regex in a variable with metacharacters expanded and then use the **unquoted** variable as the RHS of `=~` in the `[[ ... ]]` test.